# Didn't get textbox values in Controller class ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some textbox fields in my Project.I want to get the values from the text box when user clicks a button. But each time i get null value , Please help me to solve this .

**Model**

```
public class sample
{  
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
  public string Location { get; set; }
  public string tabledata { get; set; }
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
  public SomeViewModel()
  {
    samples = new List<sample>();
    //sample samplez = new sample();
  }
  public List<sample> samples { get; set; }
  public sample samplez { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

// my view name is submit

```
public ActionResult submit(sample sam)
        {
            data();
            return View();
        }
[HttpPost]
public string Index(SomeViewModel sa)
{     
  dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
  sample sam = new sample();
  sam = sa.samplez;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
  if (sam.FirstName == null || sam.LastName == null || sam.Address == null || sam.Location == null || sam.PhoneNumber == null)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sam.FirstName))
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name is required");  
    }          
  }
  else
  {
    //some code
  }
```

**view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td> 
        @Html.Label("Enter FirstName", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.samplez.FirstName, new
        {
          @class = "class1",
          title = "Enter FirstName",
          id = "NameBox",
          placeholder = "Enter name",
          onkeydown ="return TextField(event)"
        })
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    .....

  // button 
   <input type="submit" id="btnSave"  value="Save"/>
}
```

**Ajax**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("index", "sample")',
            dataType: "text",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "json",

            success: function (data) {
                // valid = data;

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('errorz');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Each time i tried to get text box values in controller function data() it will show null values only.

**Update**

now i can call the method as form action result. But how can i call this method via ajax call  ? i had included my updated code below

***controller***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult submit(SomeViewModel sa)
{
    data();
    string validator = "";
    // sample sam = new sample();
    dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
    testing sam = new testing();
    sam= sa.samplez;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
    if (sam.FirstName == null || sam.LastName == null || sam.Address == null || sam.Location == null || sam.PhoneNumber == null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sam.FirstName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name is required");
            validator = "data";
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = sam.FirstName;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Sp_Register", con);
       con.Open();
       sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", @sam.FirstName));
       sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", @sam.LastName));
       sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Address", @sam.Address));
       sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhoneNumber", @sam.PhoneNumber));
       sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Location", @sam.Location));
       sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       ViewBag.MessageText = "Ok";
    }
    return View();
}
```

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSasve").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("submit", "sample")',
            dataType: "text",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // valid = data;

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('errorz');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show your POST method. And why are you adding ModelState errors in the GET method and why are you adding the model proeprties to `ViewBag`? And all you are doing in the GET method is initializing a new `sample` so of course they will be null.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry it was a mistake actually this controller method is a post method

Comment: You need to add a parameter to receive the model. Based on your pervious question it should be `[HttpPost] public string Index(SampleVM model)` and the model will be populated with the 'new' `sample` object. But what you are doing in the controller makes no  sense anyway. Add `[Required]` attributes to your properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke now the program shows error message in ajax, when i click the button anothere method is hitting i don't know why it happend like that

Comment: @StephenMuecke sure i will add those to my controller

Comment: From the previous question, your GET method was named `data` so the POST method also needs to be `data`, or you need to specify the action and controller names in `BeginForm`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I had change the name to data but ajax show error again, when i click the save button is it possible to call a function in controller using ajax ? i think i had done something like that, is there any problem with that?

Comment: What ajax error - you have not shown any code for an ajax method (and yes, you can call the method using ajax)

Comment: What is the name of your view? it is index only right??Code you share the controller code for index page.Just want to see how samplez is being populated.
 To begin with just keep `@Html.TextboxFor(model=>model.samplez.FirstName) `.

Comment: @StephenMuecke no my view name is submit , i want to save the textbox values to db without any postback that is my aim

Comment: That is the reason your call is not going to the required method. 
 Try this
 `@using (Html.BeginForm("index","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok i will try

Comment: First use `url: '@Url.Action("Index", "sample")'` so your url is correct. Second your not even passing any data to the controller `data: $('form').serialize()` and the content type needs to be `contentType: 'json'`.

Comment: what is the need of ajax call? You can submit the form using `Html.beginForm` since you said you do not want a postback

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe am also thinking about that , i don't want any post back happen that's why i had use ajax call , now stephen is give me a way to submit my form Html.beginForm , so i have a doubt is with out ajax is it possible to submit with out postback ?

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe  waw now everything works fine , i  just avoid the ajax call ,and submit the form using using (Html.BeginForm("index","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post)) –  this

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe add answer if you want i can make it as right ans

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you help me to solve this problem using ajax , means i want to call the corresponding function when button click via ajax call

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, I have already pointed out 3 errors in my last comment. Start by fixing those.

Comment: Also `#btnSave` is a submit button, so your need to cancel the default submit action or your code will do both and ajax call and a standard submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke i had done that change the input type to button , then cancel the default submit action

Comment: @StephenMuecke change the ajax call also as per your instructions

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, Are you still having an issue? If so then edit your question with the new code you have tried and I'll have a look. Ajax is you best solution here since code such as `return(sa);` in the accepted answer will then display only the form, not the collection of existing items unless you reassign them to you model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71221/discussion-between-arunprasanth-kv-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i am still having problems , i will update the questions

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, You still haven't added `data: $('form').serialize()` to the ajax options (your not passing anything to the controller) nor have you added `return false;` to prevent the default submit (although you would be better to use `<button type="button">`. But your `submit()` method is so full of nonsense code that its not going to do what you think anyway. You have to stop coding and start learning some basics of how MVC works. Go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes sure i will do, i need to learn basics of mvc.thanks for your valid suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code i have updated a few things

**model**

```
public class sample
{  
  [Required("{0} is required")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
  public string Location { get; set; }
  public string tabledata { get; set; }
}

    public class SomeViewModel
    {
      public SomeViewModel()
      {
        samples = new List<sample>();
        //sample samplez = new sample();
      }
      public List<sample> samples { get; set; }
      public sample samplez { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.validationsummary(true)
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td> 
        @Html.Label("Enter FirstName", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.samplez.FirstName)
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    .....

  // button 
   <input type="submit" id="btnSave"  value="Save"/>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult submit(sample sam)
        {
            data();
            return View(sam);
        }
[HttpPost]
public string Index(SomeViewModel sa)
{     
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      return(sa);// this will return in case of error. 
    }
  dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
  sample sam = new sample();
  sam = sa.samplez;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
}
```

Comment: OMG. You CAN use ajax, and you should be using ajax based on your previous question. And since the model will never be invalid in your case `if(!ModelState.IsValid)` is actually pointless, but even if you do add validation attributes you have no way of displaying them!

Comment: Added @Html.ValidationSummary(true). Still client side validations wont work you need to add js scripts to make it working.Also displaying error on client side is a different task ,to get the error on server side atleast is important.

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe, you need to look at OP previous question. OP is rending a collection of items plus a form to add a new item, so a standard submit means redirecting and rendering the collection all over again. In OP's case, posting the form using ajax will greatly improve performance (and there can never be an error because there are no validation attributes).

Comment: There is no return statement in the code which has been shared. From looking at that, it looks like it is a registration page which will redirect to some standard page after success. And since @ArunprasanthKV mentioned in the comments that post back is not needed it is safe to assume he will redirect to `index` page from `submit` page.

Comment: If he wishes to use the same OP. he can pass the model in the view and populate the model as is without any difficulty. Also would you care to explain how to populate the model on a different page from the ajax call you wish to make?

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe, I don't understand your last comment. The whole point of an ajax call is you stay on the same page. The ajax calls a controller method to save the new item, then on success, adds the new item to the existing list and resets the form, avoiding the need to render the view all over again.

Comment: And what do you mean _that post back is not needed_. Your code is a post back (as is an ajax call) How on earth would you pass the form values  back to the controller without posting back?

Comment: The current view from where the form is being submitted is named as 'submit' whereas the method which is being called will return to `index`. So there is a redirection to new page. The data is not being repopulated on the same page

Comment: From view to controller is a **POST** from controller back to view is **PostBack**

Comment: Never mind, OP asked how to do it using ajax (which will give better performance), but there is no problem doing it this way.

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe now i can save the data but the problem is after submitting the form it cannot direct to the previous page i mean , when i press the save button then it redirect to a blank page

Comment: Yes because you are returning to index page of your controller. If you wish to return to the same page then `return View("submit",model)` will give you the previous page filled with data. But you wished to redirect to a new page?